# Search User Profile Property without giving ManagedPropertyName

Tags: search, powershell, user-profile, managed-property

I would like to search the users by giving the value of an user profile property. 
In order to do that, I created a new managed propery and mapped it to the corresponding crawl property.

After Full Crawl is done, I could search the users but only using the following syntax:
**myMappedProperty="something"**

And the users are listed in "People" section which contains the given search parameter.

However, I need to search the users without giving the myMappedProperty part.

I found this blog page to solve this problem:

http://gavinb.net/2014/04/14/sharepoint-2013-search-add-user-profile-properties-to-the-full-text-index/

After setting the option "Full-Text Index: PeopleIdx" in "Advanced searchable settings" dialog, I let to run the full crawl again and then it worked as I wish.

What I am trying to find out, how can I set this "PeopleIdx" option of a managed property using PowerShell, since all the managed properties in our project are created in powershell and now it should be enhanced with this setting.

Is it possible to set this option using powershell script?

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Since he references my post I figured I should answer your question. After creating your Managed Property you can set the `FullTextIndex` property like this.

```
$managedproperty.FullTextIndex = "PeopleIdx"
$managedproperty.Update()
```